# Use ref when props is ready

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, ref

```js
export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.data.length) {
      this.myRef.current.scrollToIndex({
        index: this.props.index,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        ref={this.myRef}
        data={this.props.data}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
          length: 50,
          offset: 100 * index,
          index,
        })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**Goal:**
As soon as the component renders, the FlatList should automatically scroll down to an item which has `index ===  this.props.index` (Imagin an instant messaging app, where you want to automatically scroll down to a message)

**Issue:**
Either `this.myRef` or `this.props.data` is undefined.

**Observation:**

1. `this.myRef` is ready to use only in  `componentDidMount` at the earliest.
2. `this.props` is undefined in `componentDidMount` since it takes time
    to have `this.props` read to use (By `ready` I mean, has values, is defined)
3. In `getDerivedStateFromProps` I checked to see if `this.props` is ready, however, `this.myRef` was still undefined. (Maybe it is too soon for it to get initialized)

How can I achieve my goal?

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.3
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
    Memory: 122.77 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.13.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node
    npm: 6.12.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4
```

Comment: What do you mean by *when props is ready*?

Comment: By ready I mean, has values, is defined

Comment: You don't define `this.myRef` anywhere in your code - not before or after receiving the `props`. I believe this is the issue here

Comment: `props` *are* defined when they are passed to the component, so they are definitely defined be the time `componentDidMount` is invoked. Is `data` something that is possibly `undefined` or empty array `[]` and fetched by a parent component? In this case you need to use `componentDidUpdate` to handle when `data` updates and becomes defined or something other than an empty array. This makes sense in your "messaging" example as you'd want to scroll to the bottom when new messages arrive.

Comment: Try `componentDidUpdate` hook for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is only called once after the first render but if your data is not ready then you won't have a second chance to scroll down.

You should remove your `componentDidMount` and replace it with `componentDidUpdate` to handle a change in props.data:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.data !== prevProps.data) {
        if (this.props.data.length) {
            this.myRef.current.scrollToIndex({
                index: this.props.index,
            });
        }
    }
}
```